# More useful "review queue cleared" page

Tags: feature-request, review, user-interface, moderation

Whenever a review queue is cleared, we're presented with the following screen:

[image]

I'd like to suggest making that screen a bit more useful. Having just cleared a queue, you're riding a bit of a high ("aren't I awesome?") and thus primed for further action. Presenting users with the actual review queues is more likely to yield results than showing a fairly low-key link to said queues.

Here's my quick mockup:

[image]

Note the word mockup. Suggestion. Feel free to take it somewhere better ;)

Comment: Ps.: I'm willing to bet there's others that *always* check the other queues ;)

Comment: Nice idea. Always better to give users some direct actions to do rather than require them to pick a link to go and visit. As the review page is global to all StackExchange sites this suggestion may be a better fit on the Meta.StackExchange site itself. If you like I can migrate it over there so you can get feedback from the wider community?

Comment: Sounds good Jon, cheers for the help.